# MYSQL concat with sub query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to concatenate the address fields (zip,city,countryName, streetAddress) of my table. This is the query i wrote,

```
SELECT id,concat_ws(' ',address1,zip,city,(select countryName from country where countryCode = User.countryCode))  FROM User
```

And it provides me `28 Avenue Pasteur 14390 Cabourg France` which should actually be, `27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France` (with commas separated)

How can i do achieve this?

**Update**
when used `SELECT id,concat_ws(',',address1,zip,city,(select countryName from country where countryCode = User.countryCode))  FROM User`

it gives
27 Avenue Pasteur, **14390, Cabourg**, France

but not
27 Avenue Pasteur, **14390 Cabourg**, France (no comman in between 14390 Cabourg)

Comment: Use `', '` instead of `' '`, if you want comma separators.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it gives me 28 Avenue Pasteur,14390,Cabourg,France but not 27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way (also, it is better to use `join`):

```
select u.id,concat(u.address1,', ',u.zip,' ',u.city,', ',c.countryName) as Address
from User u join
     country c on u.countryCode=c.countryCode
```

The result will be:

```
27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France
```

Comment: This isnt giving the address as output. SELECT u.id, u.address1 + ', ' + u.zip + ' ' + u.city + ', ' + c.countryName
FROM User u
JOIN country c ON u.countryCode = c.countryCode

Comment: The output is some numbers like 14418 under the column `u.address1+', '+u.zip+' '+u.city+', '+c.countryName`

Comment: @dev1234: Updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: yes its working sorry. i was trying to sort out problem and forgot to accept the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675410/mysql-subquery-and-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

You should add a comma as the delimiter of your string. Try this:

```
SELECT id,concat_ws(',',address1,zip,city,(select countryName from country where countryCode = User.countryCode))  FROM User;
```

Comment: I need the output as 27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France not as  27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390, Cabourg, France