# MYSQL subquery and Regular Expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to match result of this query with a regular expression which i am using for PHP validation.

```
select u.id,concat(u.address1,', ',u.zip,' ',u.city,', ',c.countryName) as Address
from User u join
     country c on u.countryCode=c.countryCode
```

output is

```
27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France

28 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France

30 14390 Cabourg, France

29 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France
```

I wont to match this with following regular expression and get the correct results only.

```
/^(?:\\d+ [a-zA-Z ]+, ){2}[a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

I am not sure how to get this using MYSQL **REGEXP**

something like

```
select u.id,concat(u.address1,', ',u.zip,' ',u.city,', ',c.countryName) as Address
    from User u join
         country c on u.countryCode=c.countryCode
where Address REGEXP '^st'
```

Comment: That regex won't match any of the strings due to the lack of a comma after the address house number. Seem to be other issues with it as well. Trying to solve em.

Comment: This is closer to what you are after https://regex101.com/r/zN7yT1/1. I'm not sure what modifiers mysql supports though, might need to make `[a-z]`, into `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: @icecub no it does match for 27 Avenue Pasteur, 14390 Cabourg, France

Comment: @chris85 yes it seems to fine, how can i make it with a MYSQL query pls? https://regex101.com/r/zN7yT1/1

Comment: Did you try the value with the regex on that page... or are you asking how to use a regex in mysql?

Comment: @dev1234 Well it could be me, but here's your regex and it doesn't match any of them: https://regex101.com/r/uP8qP4/1

Comment: @chris85 yes i am asking how to use it, i am new to regex with mysql

Comment: @chris85 sorry i corrected the regex. please check the question. this is my regex /^(?:\\d+ [a-zA-Z ]+, ){2}[a-zA-Z ]+$/

Comment: I can easily write the code you need to match with @chris85 regex. But I think he deserves credit for it in the first place so if he wants to do it, it should be him.

Comment: I've written a rough, untested, answer below of how this could be used.

Comment: @chris85 I'm having one issue with your regex though. It works, but it relies on modifiers. Mysql regexp doesn't support it.

Comment: Which modifier? `g` and `m` shouldn't be needed in mysql, and `i` can be made to work by adding `A-Z` to character class.

Comment: @chris85 Right. I wasn't the sure the `g` would be causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the manual, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html, a regex is used in mysql like this:

`WHERE phone REGEXP '(435)';`

now in your instance your regexp has a few issues. The regex I've updated resolves most of the issues but still one of the addresses is not found (30 14390 Cabourg, France). https://regex101.com/r/zN7yT1/1

```
select u.id,concat(u.address1,', ',u.zip,' ',u.city,', ',c.countryName) as Address
from User u join
country c on u.countryCode=c.countryCode
where concat(u.address1,', ',u.zip,' ',u.city,', ',c.countryName)
regexp '^[0-9]+,? [^,]+, [0-9]+,? [^,]+, [a-zA-Z]+$'
```

This is untested but I think should bring back the three results the regex101 finds.

Comment: will it give the same result /? if regex changed to /^(?:\\d+ [a-zA-Z ]+, ){2}[a-zA-Z ]+$/

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? I don't think `\d` is supported. There aren't delimiters.